# Expected hexadecimal code in braces after unicode escape

Tags: swift, xcode6

This worked in the first beta of Swift.

```
var degree = "\u00B0" // degree symbol
```

Now I'm getting this error and I don't understand what I need to do to correct it in Xcode 6 Beta 5.

```
Expected hexadecimal code in braces after unicode escape
```

Comment: Pro Tip: Read the release notes for each Beta release. Oh, the error message was a good one too.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
var degree = "\u{00B0}" // degree symbol
```

From the Xcode 6 beta 4 release notes:

> The \x, \u and \U escape sequences in string literals
>    have been consolidated into a single
>    and less error prone \u{123456} syntax. (17279286)

Comment: Any idea how to do when code is dynamically generated?

Comment: @BastienBeurier [here](https://replit.com/@pegasusroe/Swift-Unicode#Int+ext.swift) is an example I made on converting `Int` to emojis, hope that helps.

Comment: @BastienBeurier fix the generator

Answer (score 1):

to use a dynamically generated

```
extension String {
    func hexToDecimal() -> String {
        var myValue = self
        if self.hasPrefix("0x") || self.hasPrefix("0X") {
            let start = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
            myValue = String(self[start...])
        }

        var sum = 0
        for num in myValue.uppercased().utf8 {
            sum = sum * 16 + Int(num) - 48 
            if num >= 65 {
                sum -= 7
            }
        }
        return String(sum)
    }
}

let unicodeValue = "80" // decimal

// or 

let unicodeValue = "0x50".hexToDecimal()

if let uInt8 = UInt8(unicodeValue) {
    let scalar = UnicodeScalar(uInt8)
    let str = String(scalar)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using these lines of code we can convert hexadecimal text to the according symbol

```swift
 private func getDecodedUrl(url: String) -> String {
     let str: String = url.replacingOccurrences(of: "'\'", with: "\\")
     return str
 }

 let webUrl = NSMutableString( string: self.getDecodedUrl(url: convertedString) )
 CFStringTransform( webUrl, nil, "Any-Hex/Java" as NSString, true)
 print(webUrl)
```