# Zero Width Space in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How to create `NSString` of zero width space.

In Objective-C, I used to create like this:

```
NSString *emptyText = @"\u200B";
```

How to create it in Swift? I have tried following, but it is not working.

```
let emptyString = "\u200B"
```

Comment: `let emptyString = "\u200B"` gives the compiler error "expected hexadecimal code in braces after unicode escape", and searching for that error message would lead you quickly to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225074/expected-hexadecimal-code-in-braces-after-unicode-escape  :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this syntax in Swift

```
let emptyString = "\u{200B}"
```

Of course you can also use unicode characters directly in your Swift code.

Comment: How would the unicode character look directly in Swift?

Comment: @ShaiMishali Unicode characters (like emojis) can be used in swift directly, without using the unicode code for the character (for example instead of \u{200B} you can assign directly an emoji as a value to a string).

Comment: Using the Zero Width Space character directly in your code would probably not be a good idea since it is invisible.

Comment: @Suragch yes thery are, how to detect them if you add them by a mistake?

Comment: @Markus, I imagine you could use Xcode's search function. If that doesn't work, you could write a short method to search for them yourself.