# Incomplete universal character name in UI Testing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios9, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I am using Xcode 7's new feature : UI Testing.
After recording the interaction, Xcode generated the code automatically :

```
- (void)testDoubleTapToolBarItem {
    [[[XCUIApplication alloc] init].tabBars.buttons[@"\U5173\U6ce8"] doubleTap];
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

However, warning showed as well. Any one know how to fix this?

> Incomplete universal character name

---

**Edit: This seems to be a BUG since Xcode 7.0 GM**

Comment: If that has been generated by Xcode then it is a bug. Unicode escape sequences in Objective-C string literals are either `\uNNNN` or `\UNNNNNNNN`, in your case `@"\u5173\u6ce8"` or `@"\U00005173\U00006ce8"`.

Comment: I have no idea why all generated code of string is start with `\U`, and after I fix it to `\u`, it works.

Comment: @MartinR Another point is why the demo of WWDC 2015 is string rather than unicode ? https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=406

Comment: I haven't done the new UI testing yet, so unfortunately I cannot help you here. (I just know how Objective-C string should look like.) If you think it is a bug then you should report it at bugreporter.apple.com.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the following workaround as this seems to be a bug in xcode:

replace all **\U** to **\u** 
and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried replace \U to \u but still got error "Expected hexadecimal code in braces after unicode escape", so have to add \u{you value here}, like collectionViewsQuery.buttons["\u{6ce8}\u{518c}"].tap()

See more at [Expected hexadecimal code in braces after unicode escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225074/expected-hexadecimal-code-in-braces-after-unicode-escape)