# Swift UITesting error: Invalid escape sequence in literal. \U201c

Tags: xcode, swift, escaping, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I am building an automation suite using Xcode 7 with swift.

My app loads with the following Alert View:

Allow "Light Alarm" to access your location while you use the app?

When I record with UI Testing and click this alert I get the following code:
app.alerts["Allow \U201cLight Alarm\U201c to access your location while you use the app?"]

Note: The quotes has been replaced with \U201c

However, when I try and compile I get the following error:
"Invalid escape sequence in literal"

Anyone know how to get round this?

Comment: This seems to be an Xcode bug when generating code during UI testing, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432068/incomplete-universal-character-name-in-ui-testing for a similar issue.

Comment: Note: The problem here is *not* that OP does not know how to escape unicode characters in strings. This is code *created by Xcode* during UI test recording.

Comment: That is correct.  This is an Xcode bug when generating code. Any ideas what the code created 'should' be as per the question?

Answer (score 14):

This seems to be a bug in Xcode when generating code during UI recording.
Swift uses `\u{NNNN}` escape sequences in string literals, so

```
app.alerts["Allow \u{201c}Light Alarm\u{201c} ..."]
```

would be correct, or simply

```
app.alerts["Allow “Light Alarm“ ..."]
```

(Actually it should be `"Allow “Light Alarm” ..."` where the
second quotation mark is U+201D = RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK :)

A similar issue for UI recorded code in Objective-C was reported in
[Incomplete universal character name in UI Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432068/incomplete-universal-character-name-in-ui-testing).

I do not know a workaround, it seems that the only thing you can do
at present is to fix the code after recording (and sent a bug report
to Apple).

Comment: Its very weird as your quotes match perfectly what is on screen, but even though the UIAlertView is displayed I am getting a false boolean returned by the query:
        return app.alerts["Allow “Light Alarm” to access your location while you use the app?"].exists

Comment: @CharlieSeligman: You would have to use `app.alerts["Allow “Light Alarm“ ..."]`. – My remark *"Actually it should be ..."* was only meant as a gentle reminder that there are two different (right and left) quotation marks. Your code uses the left double quotation mark only.

Comment: Does this mean adding tags to the views or is it enough to convert the Unicode value inserted by Swift?

Comment: Any one got a work around for this? Although when I look at the xcode debugger console, the string is displayed as expected but fails when I call .exists method?

Comment: @seleniumlover see my answer below, try to install new version of Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Installing Xcode 7.3 fixed this issue for me